# when a user clicks on table tbody tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am wondering if anyone could tell me why the following is not working.

```
$("tbody[name=leadstores] tr").live('click',function(e){
        alert("clicked");
        alert(this.attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your HTML?

Comment: .live is deprecated. Any reason you have to use an old library? use .click(function(){}); instead

Comment: @IsaacFife  `click` is not good replacement for delegation method like `live()`...using `on()` is far more appropriate

Comment: If you use "on", just make sure you pass the correct signature (otherwise, you're missing out on the delegation!) 

Something like: 
$("#foo").on("click", function(){ /*..*/}) will result in the event being binded (similar to .click or bind('click'))

Instead, do: 
$("#foo").on("click", "#bar", function(){ /*..*/}) which delegates the event.

Answer (score 2):

Your underlying issue is the need to wrap `this` in a jQuery function. Otherwise you can't use jQuery's methods.

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```

Though this does not contribute to your Javascript error, you shouldn't use the `name` attribute on anything accept for input elements.

Additionally, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7. You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: The name attribute is not valid for TBODY elements. It's not restricted to INPUT elements, it's valid for all (and required by some) of the following elements: BUTTON, TEXTAREA, APPLET, SELECT, FORM, FRAME, IFRAME,IMG,A, INPUT, OBJECT, MAP, PARAM and META.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

`this` is not a jQuery object and must be wrapped in `$(this)` to use jQuery methods

Are you sure `TBODY` has a `name` attribute? Not a common thing for a `TBODY`. If it doesn't have a name then selector won't find it

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you provided does work (although, as others have pointed out, you need to wrap `this` in a jQuery wrapper.

Here's an example of your code (with some supporting HTML)

http://jsfiddle.net/Wmswm/